# How to remove the selected value from the array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to remove particular value from the array. I have written code like:

```
   $(".remove", document.getElementById("TXT")).live("click", function () {      
          $(this).parent().remove();
          var removeitem = $(this).parent().attr('id');                         
          pushvar.splice($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar), 1);

      });
```

In the above code `pushvar` is an array. Suppose if it contains 3 elements.The function will repeat for three times when we click on one of the remove button. For eg the `pushvar` contains `[5,6,7]` elements. If i click on the remove button of 6. Then the function will repeat for three times. But the

```
 pushvar.splice($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar), 1);
```

will remove all the three elements. But i want to remove only 6 from the array when i click on remove class. How can i do this.

Comment: the use of `.live()` is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/live/
use `.on()` instead

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed and removed in 1.9+

Comment: `id` cannot be just a number

Comment: post your html code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".remove", document.getElementById("TXT")).live("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var removeitem = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    if ($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar) > 0) pushvar.splice($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar), 1);
});
```

Comment: @Naidu: try this. Your code will work fine now, even if the function runs for 3 times or more...

Comment: @william actuall the function runs for two times and remove two elements every time. But i want to remove only one element on single click

Comment: it is not entering the if condition

Comment: @Naidu Because you use only number for id and $.inArray returns -1 so you convert it as integer as $.inArray(parseInt(removeitem),pushvar)

Comment: Yah you are correct but sometimes it is going inside the if and some times it is not

Comment: For the first time it is not going inside the for loop then on-wards it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var myArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var removeThis = 30;

myArray = jQuery.grep(myArray, function(data){
return data != removeThis;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`live()`  is deprecated

> jQueryversion deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

so use `on`

```
 $(".remove,#TXT").on("click", function () {      
      var removeitem = $(this).parent().attr('id');  //get parent id                        
      $(this).parent().remove(); //remove later
      pushvar.splice($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar), 1);

  });
```

if in case your selector is added dynamically then use `on`  delegate

```
  $(document).on("click", ".remove,#TXT",  function () {
```

Comment: The .on function will repeat only for one time isn't it?

Comment: no... it just adds the click event to the selector....and have nothing to do with `repeat only one time`. the above code will run as many time as user clicked the selector

Comment: I mean to say if the user click the remove class for the first time it will repeat only time and so on. Not like repeating 3 time on every remove class click

Comment: @Naidu: you're confusing `on` with `one`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
$("#TXT").on("click", ".remove", function () {      
    var removeitem = $(this).parent().remove().attr('id');     
    pushvar.splice($.inArray(removeitem, pushvar)-1, 1);
});
```

As that seems to work for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sxKrs/) , but without any HTML there's a lot of guessing ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
pushvar = [5,6,7];

$('.remove').on("click", function () {    
      var removeitem = $(this).attr('id');  
      pushvar.splice($.inArray(parseInt(removeitem), pushvar), 1);
      document.write(pushvar);
      return false;
  });
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/PBHHQ/)